# No known conversion from unique_ptr, forward declaration?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
class Base{};

class C;
class A : Base {
    unique_ptr<Base> x;
    unique_ptr<A> y;

    someMethod (){
        if (sth) {
            x = make_unique<C>(); // error no viable overloaded '=', see below
        }
    }
}

class B : Base {
    A x;
    unique_ptr<B> y;
}

class C : Base {
    B x;
}
```

How do I solve this? Sizes of the classes should be (are) determinable. That's all I know. I could make the member variables `A x` and `C x` as pointers, too, and move B and C above A but I think I would get the same error, but for A.

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'unique_ptr<C, default_delete<C>>' to 'unique_ptr<Base, default_delete<Base>>
```

Comment: You can also use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: why was the answer I was testing deleted? It said I needed to define A::someMethod after C.

Comment: Um... Several issues here, but this has no chance of compiling anyway, since `Base` is a *private* base of `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C` must be a complete type when calling `std::make_unique()`, but in your code `C` has only been forward-declared when `std::make_unique()` is called, so it doesn't know how large `C` actually is so it can allocate the `std::unique`.

Simply move the implementation of `A::someMethod()` after `C` has been fully defined (such as to a `.cpp` file), eg:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

class C;
class A : public Base {
    unique_ptr<Base> x;
    unique_ptr<A> y;

    void someMethod();
};

class B : public Base {
    A x;
    unique_ptr<B> y;
};

class C : public Base {
    B x;
};

...

void A::someMethod()
{
    if (sth) {
        x = make_unique<C>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence isn't actually true.  The instantiation of `std::make_unique` will need to see a complete definition of `C` in order to allocate and construct an instance, but the caller of `std::make_unique` doesn't need that.  Hence why the error message complains about the `unique_ptr<C>` -> `unique_ptr<Base>` conversion, not the allocation `new C{}`. The compiler will fail to create an implicit instantiation of `make_unique<C>()`, but that isn't fatal. It will emit a reference which the linker can resolve if somewhere else in the program provides a valid instantiation (maybe explicit)